# Can't import numpy after Anaconda installed

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda

I just installed Anaconda 3.5.  Terminal shows the correct version, and even has Continuum Analytics in brackets:

```
Python 3.5.0 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Oct 20 2015, 14:39:26) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

However, when I type the following:

```
>>> import numpy
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
```

I know that Anaconda comes with numpy (I ran `conda list`, just to make sure).  Anyone know what's going on?

It seems possible that my `.bash_profile` has something to do with it.  If so, the contents follow.

```
# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# added by Anaconda3 2.3.0 installer
export PATH="/Users/username/anaconda/bin:$PATH"

# Setting PATH for Python 3.5
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up uninstalling Anaconda and all versions of Python 3.  After reinstalling Anaconda, `numpy` was available.  Interestingly enough, on the version that works, Terminal shows the following information:

```
Python 3.5.0 |Anaconda 2.4.0 (x86_64)| (default, Oct 20 2015, 14:39:26) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

So apparently seeing "Continuum Analytics" does *not* mean that you're using Anaconda.